# Codeigniter always redirecting to the same method

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a system on the production server which I want to emulate in local to update it but the previous programmer have use a strange architecture. There is a codeigniter architecture and another one inside the first...

- application

  - admin (which content controller and models... probably unused)
  - common (language and models...)
  - controllers
  - js (why here...)
  - kanri

    - cache, config, controllers, core, helpers, models, views, ...
  - user

    - cache, config, controllers, core, helpers, models, views, ...
- system
- etc...

I had a lot of fun to emulate this on my local machine because all path are absolute, yeepee.
So currently, it's on my localhost, correctly configurated but when I try to login, the page just reload. I found out the method login of the controller login (so `kanri/login/login`) is called but always routed to `kanri/login/index`.

On the index page, there is only a form which redirect to the `kanri/login/login` method, so even the simple redirection do not work.

The file kanri/route.php :

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

The main .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^kanri(/(.*))?$ kanri.php?/$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user(/(.*))?$ user.php?/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

MY_Controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if($this->session->userdata('flag_admin_login')===FALSE || empty($this->session->userdata('flag_admin_login'))){
        //print "***".$this->session->userdata('member_id')."!!!!!";
        redirect('/', 'refresh');
    }
}
}
```

My Login controller :

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->router->fetch_class() . "<br/>"; // display the controller
        echo $this->router->fetch_method() . "<br/>"; //display the method
    }

    public function index(){
        //all code commented
    }

    public function login(){
        //all code commented
    }
}
```

I have a lot to work to do on it and I'm still stuck on the running... 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: using HMVC? i.e. are the controller extending `MX_Controller`?

Comment: Nop, it's extending CI_controller

Comment: Then I've got no clue how that structure was ever working. If one isn't using HMVC controllers *have* to be in the *controllers* folder.

Comment: Currently, there is a lot of controller in different folder...
In the original "controllers" folder of the initial setup, in "admin", in "kanri" and in "user"...
In the subfolder "core" of the "Kanri", there is a "MY_Controller" than I have add on the previous post, but... nothing like HMVC...

Comment: Yes, I see that, hence my comment. If it's not HMVC it must be a serious hack - in which case I doubt you'll find help on code we can't see.

Comment: I have some doubt about that because the previous programer wasn't a such good one... He should have found some tutorial to do that... -.-

Comment: In the main folder "Application" the `index.php` had been edited. 
`$application_folder = 'application/kanri';`
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
And it seem to be set in the config.php file of "Kanri"...

Comment: ah i see now what he is doing now. interesting approach. don't have any experience with that type of CI structure so I'm afraid I can't help much in this regard. i'd probably have just keep standard controllers and put all the user files in a sub folder in controllers, all the models for users in a sub folder in models .etc. the routing would have been more straightforward.

Comment: Okye :E Thanks for your time

Comment: add login controller code that helps alot and check where form is posted. is it posted to login controller of some other for validation. that should give more details on whats happening.

Comment: Actually, all the code in both method are empty. Login controller have 2 empty method : index and login, and when you try to access to the login/login method, it access to index. This is not a problem of form validation because there is no form yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple...

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```